# JavaFX - BorderPane resize bottom, top, left, right, center when drag border by mouse

Tags: javafx, pane

Is there is possibile to resize PANEs in BorderPane by moving borders by mouse ?
I would like to set up left pane to size 200, but when I set up center part to bigger size is overlapping part of left pane.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather add a component to the left pane, and set this component's preferred width.
If you are using SceneBuilder, adding a component and dragging it's border does just that.

Comment: Not helpfull, I'm not using SceneBuilder. Prefered size is not optimal when window is changing size.

Comment: Please make your question more precise - Is 200px you mention the minimum size or the preferred size? How should the left pane grow? Code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: What is the diffrent if I would like to grow left panel? 
I don't want to make it smaller in this case...